# Sklearn's roc_auc_score error when in debug mode but runs fine while running normally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, scikit-learn, pycharm

I'm using `roc_auc_score` to evaluate AUC between two arrays, the truth and the estimation. My code runs fine when I'm executing it normally on PyCharms; however, when I use the debug mode, the below strange errors pop up. I tried pausing the code prior to the `roc_auc_score` line and attempted to just run it using the debug console with just 2 small arrays. Same issue. Strangely, everything is fine using the normal Python console. Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.dtype = numeric.dtype(int_type)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/project/main-resnet.py", line 707, in <module>
    results = train_net(net=net,
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/project/main-resnet.py", line 495, in train_net
    train_auc = roc_auc_score(training_true, training_estimated)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 566, in roc_auc_score
    y_true = label_binarize(y_true, classes=labels)[:, 0]
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py", line 546, in label_binarize
    Y = sp.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(n_samples, n_classes))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 66, in __init__
    idx_dtype = get_index_dtype((indices, indptr),
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py", line 153, in get_index_dtype
    int32min = np.iinfo(np.int32).min
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.dtype = numeric.dtype(type(int_type))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
python-BaseException
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... guess I was simply googling the wrong thing :P

It seems to be an issue between PyCharms and the python version (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52137).

Switching from Python 3.10.1 to 3.9 should work.